# Proof that $f(x_0,y_0) \le f(x,y)$ for $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$$f: (x,y) \rightarrow (x-3)^2+y^2+(x-y)^2$$
Prove that: $$f(x_0,y_0) \le f(x,y) \text{ (for every } (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\text{)}$$

I know that $(2,1)$ is the only critical point of $f$, but I can not formulate a precise deduction from this fact to the thesis

Comment: what are $(x, y)$ ? Your statement is not clear

Comment: @Falcon Sorry, $(x_0,y_0)$ is the critical point and the statement is for every $(x,y)$

Comment: Rewrite as $\frac{1}{2} (x-2y)^2 + \frac {3}{2} (x-2)^2 + 3$

Comment: The question itself is unclear. Please edit it.

Comment: *NB:* "proof" and "prove" are different words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-3)^2+y^2+(x-y)^2=2x^2-2xy+2y^2-6x+9=\begin{bmatrix} x & y\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} -6x+9$$

This is a strictly convex quadratic function, the only stationary point is the global minimum.